# Not getting output on console only for jdbc in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to establish a connection to my oracle database using JDBC.
The IDE I'm using is Eclipse and I have jdbc driver and added it to eclipse as external JAR files. My source code compiles and the code runs, both without any errors; however, my data in the oracle database to which i want to connect through java is not displayed. It's not a problem of the console output either, because I tested that.

Here is my source code for database connection,

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.sql.*;
public class jdbc {
    public static void main(String args[]) {  
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "system", "db501"
                );
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from jdbc ");
            while(rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+" "+rs.getInt(2));  
            }
            con.close();
        } catch(Exception e) { 
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Already i have imported those files  in the above source code but there is no console output ... !

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue, after long analysis identified the problem.
The issue was in database.

In sqlplus, i created table and inserted data but forgot to give commit. 
Give, sql>commit; 
After inserting the data. Then run this jdbc code.
I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following imports

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
```

or

```
 import java.sql.*;
```